# Laplace transform coming out to infinity

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Trying to find the Laplace transform of  $$\frac{\cos t}{t}.$$ 
It comes out as infinity, but that doesn't make any sense.

Does this mean that this function doesn't have a Laplace transform or is something wrong here?

Comment: Applying L[f(t)/t] as integral s to infinity, L[f(t)] .. .. I got the integral as log(s^2 +1) which in applying limits comes to infinity

Comment: Basically $\frac{\cos t}{t}$ is unbounded near $0$ and in fact behaves like $1/t$ here. This is why you are getting $\infty$. The integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos t}{t} e^{-st}\,dt$ will not exist for any $s$. (Remember $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}\, dt$ is infinite.)

Comment: Umm.. so how does that affect the Laplace?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha still computes an answer https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+of+cos(t)%2Ft which I suspect is a distributional Laplace transform of the renormalised distribution of $\frac{\cos t}t$

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's the correct transform for $\cos t$ multiplied by the distributional derivative of $(\ln t)_+$, that is, $-\int_0^\infty \ln(t) \,\frac d {dt} (\cos(t) \,e^{-s t}) \,dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to find (solving a more general problem):

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{t}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{t}\cdot\exp\left(-\text{s}t\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the '[frequency-domain integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{t}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_\text{s}^\infty\mathcal{L}_t\left[\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag2$$

Using the [table of selected Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms), we find:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+\text{n}^2}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{t}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_\text{s}^\infty\frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2+\text{n}^2}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag4$$

Let's substitute $\text{u}:=\sigma^2+\text{n}^2$, so we get:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{t}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\int_{\text{s}^2+\text{n}^2}^{\epsilon^2+\text{n}^2}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\left[\ln\left|\text{u}\right|\right]_{\text{s}^2+\text{n}^2}^{\epsilon^2+\text{n}^2}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\left(\ln\left|\epsilon^2+\text{n}^2\right|-\ln\left|\text{s}^2+\text{n}^2\right|\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\left|\frac{\epsilon^2+\text{n}^2}{\text{s}^2+\text{n}^2}\right|\to\infty\tag5$$

Comment: Yeah that's how I got infinity. But I'm not sure what that means... If Laplace comes as infinity. Shouldn't Laplace be a function of S?

Comment: @ULTIMATEGAMER07 Your conclusion should be that the Laplace transform does not exists.

Comment: Oh..ok thanks. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @ULTIMATEGAMER07 You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help you!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives an answer, and I suspect it is in a sense the correct answer(interpreting $\cos t/t$ as a renormalised distribution) like how you can still compute some fourier transforms without the integral converging.  But i haven't done this computation to see if this is why Wolfram Alpha brings out the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Do you know about this?